# How to see who already downloaded our app in play console closed testing?

Tags: android

I want to monitor internal testers who have or have not downloaded the app. is there a feature in play console?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell you can't specifically see who has downloaded the app - you can however see the number of users on a certain app version in the Statistics section > https://play.google.com/console/u/1/developers/download-reports/statistics

If that's not enough - I would write up a custom db update to record a user's specific version.

Comment: this doesn't include the closed testing versions